# when I try to use tkinter on visual studio I keep getting the same error about background colour

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

when I try to use Tkinter making a simple program on my manjaro linux in visual code studio but when I go to use the program I keep getting the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/riley/Documents/hello.py", line 2, in <module>
root = Tk()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2262, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects,                
useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "BACKGROUND"
```

I've tried several thing to get it working with the different way of imported and different ways of writing root = Tk()
but i still keep getting the same error
here is the code that I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
hello =Label(root, Text="hello")
hello.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I do an internet search on that exact error I get a lot of results. Have you done any research into this problem and tried suggested fixes before asking this question here?

Comment: I got different error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Text"` when running your code.